# How to make a true ranking by giving same ranking to same score while the rest follow the true order?

Tags: r, data.table

Here is the toy sample of 8 students with grades from A to D. I would like to give a ranking which reflects the true order while students with same grade shall have same ranking.
It seems the .GRP is most likely the right approach, but it goes with order of numbers, how can I skip the position occupied by the students with same grade, with data.table? Thanks.

```
DT <- data.table(GRADE = c("A","B","B","C",rep("D",4)))
DT[, GRP:=.GRP, by = GRADE][, RANK:= c(1,2,2,4,5,5,5,5)]

#   GRADE GRP RANK
#1:     A   1    1
#2:     B   2    2
#3:     B   2    2
#4:     C   3    4
#5:     D   4    5
#6:     D   4    5
#7:     D   4    5
#8:     D   4    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `frank`

```
DT[, RANK := frank(GRADE, ties.method = 'min')]
DT$RANK
#[1] 1 2 2 4 5 5 5 5
```

---

Or in `dplyr` with `min_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
   mutate(RANK = min_rank(GRADE))
```